# Start a Java/Hibernate Webapp outside Eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications

As a intern, I'm currently developping a java webapp for the first time. I access a Oracle database with Hibernate framework, and use javascript and Jquery on client side.

Everything works smoothly as long as I stay in Eclipse. However, in order to deploy my application, I need to be able to launch it outside Eclipse.

Here's what I did until now : Right-clic on my projet -> Export -> Java/Runnable JAR File (with "Copy required librairies into a sub-folder net to the generated JAR", or it won't works)

I got a jar file (and a folder with a lot of jar libraries), and it runs lovely when executing it with java -jar -myJar.jar with Windows command prompt. 
If I try to load a web page from my browser, the server answers (important to notice !) with a 404 error : it can't find the html page.
I can't figure out where I shoul put my webapp folder, which contains every html, css and js file.

Can you help me ? Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Are you working with an embedded server in your app or do you want/need to generate a war instead?

Comment: There are a few things you should check.  #1. What app server are you using?  Hibernate is not a app server afaik.  #2.  You may need a WAR file rather than a JAR file.  Look up WAR file in the web, it should tell you where to put the welcome page (html)

Comment: Thank you. I have an embedded Tomcat in my app, I don't think I need any other external server... But I may be wrong ^^'